# somar data frames diferentes com base nos nomes das colunas

Tags: r, data.frame

preciso muito da ajuda de vocês para terminar uma análise.
tenho as seguintes tabelas (data frames):

```
df1<-data.frame(c(0,1,1,0),c(1,0,0,1),c(1,1,0,0))
colnames(df1)<-c("0","0.5","1")
df2<-data.frame(c(1,1,1,0),c(0,1,0,0))
colnames(df2)<-c("0","0.5")
df3<-data.frame(c(1,1,1,1),c(0,0,0,1))
colnames(df3)<-c("0.5","1")
```

entendam que para a análise funcionar eu preciso que as três tabelas tenham obrigatoriamente as colunas de nome 0, 0.5 e 1.
Eu pensei em somar todas as tabelas com uma tabela molde contendo as três colunas e valores todos igual a zero, mas ainda não consegui resolver isso. 
Vocês acham que essa é a solução? Como posso fazer isso?
Obrigada pessoal!!

Answer (score 3):

Desculpe amigos, era muito fácil

```
molde<-data.frame(c(0,0,0,0),c(0,0,0,0),c(0,0,0,0))
colnames(molde)<-c("0","0.5","1")

melted <- cbind(df2,molde)
aggr <- as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, by(t(melted),INDICES=names(melted),FUN=colSums)))
```

de qualquer forma obrigada